# stripos equivalent in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

How do I find the first position of a string within another string (column) in MySQL, case insensitive?

I want to be able to sort based on this returned number – string position.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`INSTR(str,substr)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_instr):

> Returns the position of the first occurrence of substring `substr` in string `str`. This is the same as the two-argument form of `LOCATE()`, except that the order of the arguments is reversed.

```
SELECT INSTR('foobarbar', 'bar');
    -> 4
SELECT INSTR('xbar', 'foobar');
    -> 0
```

Comment: Thanks for such a quick and detailer answer.

Answer (score 4):

Try to use [Locate()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_locate)

```
SELECT LOCATE('bar', 'fooBARBAR'); // return 4
```

Also, mysql comparison based on collation. For example.

```
SET NAMES 'binary';
SELECT LOCATE('bar', 'fooBARBAR'); // return 0
```

Remember it.

Also, read [Case Sensitivity in String Searches](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/case-sensitivity.html)

Comment: Quirky that it's the same function as `INSTR()` but arguments reversed. I like having the column name first, though, more logical that way.

Answer (score 3):

Check out [INSTR](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_instr). It should let you do that.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for. Now whom to give the accept? :)

Comment: @silkfire I'd usually go with whoever was first, or whichever is most detailed, if the answers are almost the same.

Comment: @DannyBeckett Well just because I like the British so much :) There you go. Everyone has 3 upvotes, fair enough?